# jQuery Flot: Two x-axes, one dataset

Tags: javascript, jquery, flot

With Flot, is it possible to use two x-axes with one dataset?

**y** = altitude, **x1** (bottom) = time (timestamp), **x2** (top) = distance (km)

```
data = [[timestamp, altitude, km], [...]]
```

Comment: Maybe I would need to somehow have data for y and x1 like [timestmap, altitude], and another dataset for x1 and x2, like [timestamp, km] ?

Comment: Yep, you've got the right idea there - make 2 data sets and attach them to 2 different axes.